# CSS/XHTML & Static Webpages?

Tags: css, xhtml, static

I'm trying to get this webpage to look a bit more static. 
On smaller resolutions the text will not fit inside of the div elements correctly. 
The website is here: http://www.vidimortem.info/

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
   width: auto;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
div  {
   border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

/* class identifiers */
.alignmentDiv {
   width: inherit;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   color: #000000;
 }

.headerDiv {
   background-color: #318B7C; 
   width: inherit;
   height: 40px;
   margin: auto auto; 
   border-radius: 15px; /* i'm currently hating how css3 hasn't fully been implemented to all themes so it doesn't colorize. */ 
   opacity: 0.8;
}
.sidebarDiv   {
   background-color: #748B31; 
   width: 40%;
   height: 220px; 
   padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
   display: inline-block;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
.linksDiv {
   background-color: #ACACAC; 
   width: 40%;
   height: 200px; 
   padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
   font-size: 14px;
   display: block;
   float: right;
   text-align: justify;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
.aboutDiv     {
   background-color: #468B31;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #ccc;
   width: 50%; 
   height: 130px;
   padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
   margin: auto auto;
   margin-top: 3%;
   font-size: 11px;
   display: block; 
   text-align: justify;
}

a {
   color: #F92672;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover {
   color: #FC689D;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I want to make this as static as possible **without** altering the appearance substantially. 
The HTML can be found here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=L0xBLau2 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: I am asking why my elements aren't exactly static. See, if you minimize the window the text won't fit quite as well, thereby, this implies that some resolutions may not be compatible with it. So I'd like to make it static as possible without giving it much of a noticeable heterogeneity.

Comment: If you don't want your divs to shrink down, don't apply `width` in `%`, use `px` or `em`.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean by static? It's supposed to be the same for all monitors. Using pixels is unsturdy to extremities.

Comment: For many reasons your site will never look *exactly* the same, only *more or less* the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Change CSS this way:

```
body {
   width: 1070px;
   margin: auto;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: What about people who have 800 by 600 monitors? Wouldn't that suck?

Comment: Ah, my apologies! I have just tried it and it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the height of the boxes.